# Sending string as byte array from C# to Java via socket

Tags: java, c#

I am trying the following:

**C# Client:**

```
    string stringToSend = "Hello man";
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mClientSocket.GetStream(),Encoding.UTF8);

    //write number of bytes:
    byte[] headerBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(stringToSend.Length);
    mClientSocket.GetStream().Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
    //write text:
    byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSend);
    writer.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
```

**Java Server:**

```
   Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), utf8));

   while (true) {
       //we read header first
      int headerSize = in.read();
      int bytesRead = 0;
      char[] input = new char[headerSize];

      while (bytesRead < headerSize) 
      {     
         bytesRead += in.read(input, bytesRead, headerSize - bytesRead);
      }
            String resString = new String(input);
            System.out.println(resString);


       if (resString.equals("!$$$")) {
                break;
       }
   }
```

The string size equals 9.That's correct on both sides.But, when I am reading the string iteself on the Java side, the data looks wrong.The char buffer ('input' variable)content looks like this:

> ",",",'H','e','l','l','o',''

I tried to change endianness with reversing the byte array.Also tried changing string encoding format between ASCII and UTF-8.I still feel like it relates to the endianness problem,but can not figure out how to solve it.I know I can use other types of writers in order to write text data to the steam,but I am trying using raw byte arrays for the sake of learning.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. But, it appears that on the Java side of the code you are simply not reading the string length correctly. The `in.Read()` method is going to read a single character, but you need to read four bytes for the integer you sent from the C# side. Not only should you read bytes directly (don't interpret them as UTF8 characters), you need to read the right amount and then decode that as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Also: endianness does not affect ASCII or UTF8. It could affect transmission of the 32-bit integer, but you say that's fine. So, endianness does not seem to be your problem. You are mixing `BinaryWriter` with using `NetworkStream` directly, which seems pointless and prone to error. But I also don't think that's your problem. If fixing the integer read on the Java side doesn't solve your problem, please fix the question so it's answerable.

Comment: You are sending header length as a 4 byte integer from c# but only reading a single byte on the javaside to get that value. The next three bytes on the stream are 0, 0, 0 which java is converting to empty characters in you input. See my answer below.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the example is completely fine.If you see my code,then you also understand that the only missing part there is instantiation of the socket object.That's it.Please,don't make SO a nasty place to visit with those 'over-pedantic' remarks.My question is very clear and the code sample is quite informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These

```
byte[] headerBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(stringToSend.Length);
```

are 4 bytes. And they aren't character data so it makes no sense to read them with a `BufferedReader`. Just read the bytes directly.

```
byte[] headerBytes = new byte[4];
// shortcut, make sure 4 bytes were actually read
in.read(headerBytes);
```

Now extract your text's length and allocate enough space for it

```
int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(headerBytes).getInt();
byte[] textBytes = new byte[length];
```

Then read the text

```
int remaining = length;
int offset = 0;
while (remaining > 0) {
    int count = in.read(textBytes, offset, remaining);
    if (-1 == count) {
        // deal with it
        break;
    }
    remaining -= count;
    offset += count;
}
```

Now decode it as UTF-8

```
String text = new String(textBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and you are done.

Endianness will have to match for those first 4 bytes. One way of ensuring that is to use "network order" (big-endian). So:

C# Client

```
byte[] headerBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(stringToSend.Length));
```

Java Server

```
int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(headerBytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

Comment: Yep,that's it.Now it gets ok. Though I used Array.Reverse on C# side to flip the bytes order for big endian. It is interesting that I don't have to do that for the string part.Your endian converter line doesn't work.There is no matching constructor for HostToNetworkOrder

Comment: @MichaelIvanov I think Tom just had a typo in the order of the invocation. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it appears you have a problem with your indexes.

You C# code is sending an integer converted to 4 bytes.

But you Java Code is only reading a single byte as the length of the string.

The next 3 bytes sent from C# are going to the three zero bytes from your string length.

You Java code is reading those 3 zero bytes and converting them to empty characters which represent the first 3 empty characters of your input[] array.

**C# Client:**

```
string stringToSend = "Hello man";
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mClientSocket.GetStream(),Encoding.UTF8);

//write number of bytes: Original line was sending the entire string here. Optionally if you string is longer than 255 characters, you'll need to send another data type, perhaps an integer converted to 4 bytes.
byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSend);
mClientSocket.GetStream().Write((byte)textBytes.Length);
//write text the entire buffer

writer.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
```

**Java Server:**

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), utf8));

while (true) {
    //we read header first
    // original code was sending an integer as 4 bytes but was only reading a single char here.
    int headerSize = in.read();// read a single byte from the input
    int bytesRead = 0;
    char[] input = new char[headerSize];

    // no need foe a while statement here:
    bytesRead = in.read(input, 0, headerSize);

    // if you are going to use a while statement, then in each loop
    // you should be processing the input but because it will get overwritten on the next read.
    String resString = new String(input, utf8);
    System.out.println(resString);


    if (resString.equals("!$$$")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new String(input)`: I think you meant `new String(input, utf8)`. (Otherwise, the character encoding varies across machines, users and time.)